# Android emulator for testing video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-emulator

This is something I haven't seen anyone ask and there is no information on it.

I am building a video app, currently I am testing the UI in GenyMotion and on my device. But the problem is that GenyMotion doesn't support video (H.246). This means that I can't test video related functions on different devices.

This is a must, as I compiled ffmpeg and need to test how it reacts on different devices. I have tried android emulator as well, with no luck.

Have someone come across this issue and is there any other emulator out there that doesn't only support 3gp format?

Comment: Did you try emulator from sdk with x86/x64 system image and enabled host gpu?

Comment: Yes it supports video, but the quality is horrible. For a app that focuses mainly on video, I would like to test quality of conversion etc. --- and it only supports video taken from camera as far as I know, I can not upload a video and let it display in the gallery, only in sdcard/downloads